# Is the big O runtime of my function N^2 or N log N?

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o, complexity-theory

```
from linkedlist import LinkedList

def find_max(linked_list): #  Complexity: O(N)
  current = linked_list.get_head_node()
  maximum = current.get_value()
  while current.get_next_node():
    current = current.get_next_node()
    val = current.get_value()
    if val > maximum:
      maximum = val
  return maximum

def sort_linked_list(linked_list):  # <----- WHAT IS THE COMPLEXITY OF THIS FUNCTION?
  print("\n---------------------------")
  print("The original linked list is:\n{0}".format(linked_list.stringify_list()))
  new_linked_list = LinkedList()

  while linked_list.head_node:
    max_value = find_max(linked_list)
    print(max_value)
    new_linked_list.insert_beginning(max_value)
    linked_list.remove_node(max_value)

  return new_linked_list
```

Since we loop through the while loop N times, the runtime is at least N. For each loop we call find_max, HOWEVER, for each call to find_max, the linked_list we are parsing to the find_max is reduced by one element. Based on that, isn't the runtime `N log N`?

Or is it `N^2`?

Comment: What's 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1) + n?

Comment: Nope, you're still N^2. Reducing the size of the list each time means you're 1/2 N^2, but that's just a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still `O(n²)`; the reduction in size by 1 each time just makes the effective work `n * n / 2` (because on average, you have to deal with half the original length on each pass, and you're still doing `n` passes). But since constant factors aren't included in big-O notation, that simplifies to just `O(n²)`.

For it to be `O(n log n)`, each step would have to *halve* the size of the list to scan, not simply reduce it by one.

Comment: Thanks, I especially liked your last comment on when the runtime is O(n log n), that really cleared out a lot!

Comment: Note: I wrote `n * n / 2`, when it's technically `n * (n + 1) / 2`. But the addition matters even less than the constant divisor here, and omitting it made it clearer when I talked about dealing with an average of half the original length on each pass.

Comment: @xingZì: Glad it helped. I'll note that technically, it doesn't have to specifically halve the size. Halving would get you a base-2 log, which is usually what people mean when discussing complexity (because divide and conquer is usually naturally done by halving at each step). Technically, any approach that applies a fixed divisor after each step (e.g. reducing the length by a third, or a quarter, or by two thirds, or whatever) would be a form of `O(n log n)`, but 99% of the time, the log people refer to is base-2, and it refers to algorithms that involve splitting into halves in some way.

Comment: By the way, all the answers seem to neglect `linked_list.remove_node(max_value)`, which I assume has a runtime of N? Won't this make the function O(N^3)?

Comment: @xingZì: That's an additive step, not multiplicative. And it has the same behavior as the find step (`(n + 1) / 2` average work per step), so incorporating it just means the work is `n * ((n + 1) / 2 + (n + 1) / 2)`; combine the two `(n + 1) / 2`s and it simplifies to `n * (n + 1)`. The `+ 1` is ignored for big-O, so it's still `O(n²)`. The code would be faster if the `find_max` function returned the maximum node (so it could be removed with `O(1)` work, instead of searched for at `O(n)`), but the big-O is the same; the algorithm may take twice as long, but it will scale identically.

Answer (score 4):

It's `n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1` which is arithmetic sequence so it is `n(n+1)/2`. So in big O notation it is O`(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, O-notation deals in terms of worst-case complexity, and describes an entire *class* of functions. As far as O-notation goes, the following two functions are the same complexity:

```
64x^2 + 128x + 256           --> O(n^2)
x^2 - 2x + 1                 --> O(n^2)
```

In your case (and your algorithm what's called a *selection sort*, picking the best element in the list and putting it in the new list; other `O(n^2)` sorts include *insertion sort* and *bubble sort*), you have the following complexities:

```
0th iteration: n
1st iteration: n-1
2nd iteration: n-2
...
nth iteration: 1
```

So the entire complexity would be

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1  =  n(n+1)/2  =  1/2n^2 + 1/2n
```

which is still `O(n^2)`, though it'd be on the low side of that class.